# Метка строки в js

Tags: javascript

Что в js означает следующая конструкция:

```
какой_то_ключ: выражение
```

Мне известно, что для циклов используется подобный синтаксис. Напр:

```
внешний_цикл: while (true) {
    while (true) {
        if (true) {
            break внешний_цикл
        }
    }
}
```

Но данный синтаксис не бросает исключение в любых выражениях:

```
key: 1 + 3
// Выведет: 4
```

Самое глупое, что даже не знаю как это называется и потому не могу найти информацию в сети.

Есть ли в этом смысл в этом? Используется для каких-то иных целей подобные конструкции? Или может в js планировался goto и это рудимент тех времён?

Comment: в javaScript такая конструкция называется меткой или label. Но зачем она нужна в  таком случае как Вы указали, я не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это так и называется: [метка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Может быть использована вместе с операторами [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) и [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)

> Вы можете использовать метки для идентификации цикла, и затем использовать `break` или `continue`, чтобы показать должна ли программа прервать цикл или продолжить выполнение.
>
> Обратите внимание, что в JavaScript **НЕТ** оператора `goto`, вы можете использовать метки только в паре с `break` или `continue`.

Comment: Забавно, часть ответа содержится в вопросе. Думал как озаглавить, на ум пришло слово «метка», написал. Потом загуглил со словом «метка» и сразу же нашел :D

Но я так полагаю, кроме циклов нигде не используется

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145345/discussion-on-answer-by-grundy----js); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.